# Process not defined

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I created an app with create-react-app without ejected config. 
When I try to access the process it is always undefined.

I added an .env file in the root folder, with a key

```
REACT_APP_PREFILL_URL=SOMEURL
```

After I start yarn or npm start, I get "process is not defined"

Here is my code

```
 return axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_PREFILL_URL,
            headers: {
                'x-api-key': process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_API_KEY,
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store',
                Pragma: 'no-cache',
            },
            data: {
                country: 'de',
            },
            timeout: 30000,
            validateStatus: status => status === 200,
        }).then(response => response.data.id);
```

Comment: I worked with older versions of create-react-app and was not aware of this feature, pretty cool but too bad it does not work... ^^' Did you check your version numbers?

Comment: Yeah, i use the current Version. Maybe i should switch to dotenv

Comment: Could it be something simple, like you don't run npm scripts from the project folder or a permission problem?

Comment: That was my first idea, but nope, im running from the correct folder and all permissions looks good